# static const error C2864

Tags: c++

Перенимаю проект бывшего рабочего в комании. Проект был разработан на GL Studio и генирирует очень много файлов сам, т.е программирования как такого, не так много. При компиляции проекта, произошла ошибка которую я никак не могу понять.

файл с ошибками:

```
#pragma once

#include "aladintypes.h"
#include "gls_text_box.h"
#include "ProgressBar.h"


// panels to forward information to
#include "Oberes_Zusatzpanel.h"
#include "Panel_Flug.h"

// std:: headers
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

/*
 *                  VIEW HUB
 *
 * Forwards information recieved by Drone Connection
 * to elements of the GUI for display.
 * For faster access it uses GLStudio's FindByName method only once
 * on initialization and stores the link in a pointer using the
 * method gatherLinksToDisplays().
 *
 * throws logic_error if elements of the UI cannot be found by name
 *
 * */

class ViewHub
{
public:

    ViewHub( void );

    void setLinks(  disti::Oberes_ZusatzpanelClass *,
                    disti::Panel_FlugClass *,
                    disti::ProgressBarClass *downlinkProgressBar );

    // send information to panels linked
    void showNotConnected( void );
    void showStateResponse( est::aladin::SystemStateResponse & );

    int roundToInt( double );
    std::string currentTimeAsString();
    std::string geoCoordToString( double coord, bool isLat );

private:

    // NAME Literals of the elements for display
    const char *NAME_UPPER_PANEL = "Oberes_Zusatzpanel_Informationsbereich_Text";
    const char *NAME_PANEL_FLIGHT_TEXT_BOX = "customTextBox";
    //$$ NOTE :  "customTextBox" is the name of a dummy TextBox I've put
    //$$          on top of the original textbox derived for readability.
    //$$         The Original name is : "Panel_Flug_Textfeld_gross_text"

    // Links to the elements for display
    disti::GlsTextBox *m_oberesZusatzpanelTextBox = nullptr;
    disti::GlsTextBox *m_panelFlugTextBox = nullptr;
    disti::ProgressBarClass *m_downlinkProgressBar = nullptr;

    void writePanelFlug( est::aladin::SystemStateResponse &response );
    void writeOberesZusatzpanel( est::aladin::SystemStateResponse &response );

    // Converts the postition provided by the parameter in the correct
    // format for display in the panels
    std::string positionAsString( est::aladin::DynamicsState & );

    // called in constructor
    void gatherLinksToDisplays( disti::Oberes_ZusatzpanelClass &,
                                disti::Panel_FlugClass & );

    // convert to string adding a leading zero
    // in case the parameter is smaller than ten
    // used by positionAsString
    std::string twoDig( int );
};
```

Следующие ошибки вылазию при компиляции:

```
error C2864: 'ViewHub::NAME_UPPER_PANEL' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
error C2864: 'ViewHub::NAME_PANEL_FLIGHT_TEXT_BOX' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
 error C2864: 'ViewHub::m_oberesZusatzpanelTextBox' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
 error C2864: 'ViewHub::m_oberesZusatzpanelTextBox' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
error C2864: 'ViewHub::m_downlinkProgressBar' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
```

Comment: @Abyx как еще можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: @Insider: "генирирует очень много файлов сам"? Ну так а вот эти файлы, в которых ошибки - это сгенерированные файлы или рукописные? Почему в вопросе это не уточняется?

Comment: @AnT потому что данное не известно и спросить не у кого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в таких строках:

```
class ViewHub{
    //...
    const char *NAME_PANEL_FLIGHT_TEXT_BOX = "customTextBox";
    //...
};
```

Компилятор вам прямо говорит, что таким образом можно инициализировать только статические целочисленные константы. Решения два:

1) Включите поддержку C++11. Там такие трюки прокатывают.
2) Инициализируйте все поля в конструкторах:

```
class ViewHub{
    //...
    const char *NAME_PANEL_FLIGHT_TEXT_BOX;
    ViewHub():
        NAME_PANEL_FLIGHT_TEXT_BOX("customTextBox")
    {}
    //...
};
```

Comment: подскажите, как провернуть такое же с к примеру `disti::GlsTextBox *m_oberesZusatzpanelTextBox = nullptr;`

Comment: @Insider, хмм что-то странное у вас там происходит. `nullptr` тоже из C++11. Возможно ваш компилятор не полностью поддерживает C++11. Попробуйте использовать более позднюю версию, или перепишите код на C++03